# Quero clicar em um link quando eu clicar mostrar uma div e quando eu clicar em outro link mostrar uma outra div e desaparecer a anterior

Tags: jquery, toggle

É simples mas não estou conseguindo fazer. 
Quando eu clicar no link1 mostrar a div1, e se eu clicar no link2 mostrar a div2.
E se eu clicar no link1 novamente com a div1 mostrando ela deve desaparecer, sei que tenho que usar o metodo toggle mas não estou conseguindo.

```js
$('.zik').click(function() {
  $("#div1").hide();
  $("#div2").hide();
});
$(".teste").click(function() {
  $("#div1").toggle(
    function() {
      //                            $("#treta").hide();
    },
    function() {
      //                            $("#treta").show();
    });
  $("#div2").toggle(
    function() {
      //                            $("#treta").hide();
    },
    function() {
      //                            $("#treta").show();
    });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="link1" class="teste">link1</a>
<a id="link2" class="teste">link2</a>

<div id="div1">

</div>

<div id="div2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar qual link está sendo clicado para "togglar" a `div` correta:

```js
$(".teste").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') == 'link1') {
    $("#div1").toggle();
    $("#div2").hide();
  } else {
    $("#div2").toggle();
    $("#div1").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="link1" class="teste">link1</a>
<a id="link2" class="teste">link2</a>

<div id="div1">

</div>

<div id="div2">

</div>
```

Comment: É quase isto amigo, vamos lá, cliquei no link1: div1 apareceu Ok.
Agora se caso eu no link2 a div1 deve desaparecer.

Comment: Editei @DeveloperWebSistem..., veja se é isso

Comment: Exatamente amigo!
Obrigado.